# Action recognition mobile Application

Tags: python, java, flutter, react-native, tensorflow-lite

I am going to create a mobile application for dynamic sign language using action recognition. is it possible? what is the best technology for that? how can I start it?

I am trying to make a flutter application. but there tflite and flutter application display some error.
"The plugin tflite uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding. To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs."

how can I create this?

Answer (score 0):

On android/app/build.gradle
Add
aaptOptions {
noCompress 'tflite'
noCompress 'lite'
}

Ensure you use more recently version
Check on https://pub.dev/packages/tflite
The last version